# Tracking membership profiles with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

On a site with a searchable directory of members, is there a way to track how many users are clicking on each member profile, and how many users click on the contact button within each profile (i.e. rather than just general clicks, can you track specific profile clicks with google analytics)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be as follows:

1. Define a hit scoped dimension called "Member ID" (assume index 1)
2. Define a hit scoped metric called "Profile Clicks" (assume index 1) with type Integer
3. Define a hit scoped metric called "Profile Contacts" (assume index 2) with type Integer

Whenever a user clicks on a member profile, send a Google Analytics event as follows:

```
Event Category = Profile
Event Action = Click
Custom Dimension 1 = <member_id> e.g. 123
Custom Metric 1 = 1
```

Whenever a user clicks on the contact button within the profile page, send a Google Analytics event as follows:

```
Event Category = Profile
Event Action = Contact
Custom Dimension 1 = <member_id> e.g. 123
Custom Metric 2 = 1
```

To send a Google Analytics event with custom dimensions and metrics (assuming you are not using Google Tag Manager), you would execute this code:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', '123');
ga('set', 'metric1', 1);
ga('send', 'event', 'Profile', 'Click');
```

More info on passing custom dimensions and metrics to GA can be found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en).

If you're using Google Tag Manager, then you would need to push the values of the custom dimensions and metrics onto the GTM dataLayer and then configure a Google Analytics event tag to fire and pick up the values.

Comment: Thank you!  Just to clarify, once I've set up my dimensions and metrics, when you refer to this:

``Event Category = Profile
Event Action = Click
Custom Dimension 1 = <member_id> e.g. 123
Custom Metric 1 = 1``

Do I need to specify that code somehwere ? Or it is captured in 
`ga('set', 'dimension1', '123');`

Additionally, can the values in '123' be anything, or does it tie back to a specific value created with the dimension or metric?

Comment: In the `ga('send', 'event', 'Profile', 'Click');` command, the third and fourth parameters are the `Category` and `Action` respectively. In my example, `123` is supposed to be an example member ID. So in your case, you would need to dynamically insert the actual member ID of the profile that was clicked.

Comment: Thank you.  Does the code containing the variables that hold the parameters (i.e. Event Category, Event Action etc), go inside the script that contains ga('set', 'dimension1', '123') or does that go somewhere inside google analytics?

Comment: You specify the event category and action using the `ga('send', 'event', 'Profile', 'Click');` command. The third and fourth parameters are the event category and action respectively. So the order of the code is 1) set custom dimensions then 2) set custom metrics then 3) send the event.